# PHP Submitting form with images. Access that image on the next page

Tags: php

I am having issues trying to access a submitted image from a form on the next page.

Here is my php in my html.

I am looping through a folder of images and echoing them onto the page.

```
<form action = "Order_Form.php"
    method = "post"
    enctype = "multipart/form-data">
<?php
    $files = glob("images/*.*");
    $count = 0;


for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{ 
 $num = $files[$i]; 

    if($count == 4){
      echo "<br>";
      $count = 0;
    }
    $count++;


    echo '<input type="image" src="'.$num.'" 
    alt="img"  name="image" class = "galImgs" value="submit"  />';
}


?>
</form>
```

And now on submit I proceed to Order_Form.php

I want to display the picture the user clicked/submitted to the page.
I have been trying with

```
      $nm = $_POST['image'];      
      echo '<img src="/files/images/.$nm" class= "image"/>';
```

Im pretty sure it has to be something simple, but after much googling and trial & error I can't seem to figure this out.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of your button will be that of it's `value` attribute, or always `Submit`.

Use an array of images in the `$_POST` by appending `[$num]` to the input `name` attribute.

```
echo '<input type="image" src="'.$num.'" 
    alt="img"  name="image[' . $num . ']" class = "galImgs" value="submit"  />';
```

This will send the input `image` to `$_POST` as an array which looks like

```
// Suppose two of them (22 & 14) were clicked (which isn't actually possible but illustrates it)
// The values are always "submit" but the keys are useful to you.
array(1) {
  ["image"]=>
  array(2) {
    [22]=>
    string(6) "submit"
    [14]=>
    string(6) "submit"
  }
}
```

Then when you retrieve it from `$_POST`, you know which has been clicked:

```
foreach ($_POST['image'] as $im=>$num) {
   // The array key holds the image number
  echo '<img src="/files/images/' .$im .'" class= "image"/>';
}
```

Comment: @user1263186 Great, happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark beside it if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Your $nm variable it not being interpretted because it is in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have an easier time if you simply use normal `<img>` tags with an onClick event that sets a hidden input field to the value of the selected image.